# how to pass the value of the checkbox in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have the following bit of haml code

```
%section.form
  %form.standard{action: registration_index_path, method: 'get'}
    %fieldset{"aria-labelledby" => "content-header"}
      %legend 
      %ul
        %li
          %label{for: "Associate-id"} Associate Id
          %input#Associate-id{name: "id", size: "80", type: "text", value: current_user.associate_username}/
        %li
          %label{for: "email"} Email
          %input#email{name: "email", size: "80", type: "text", value: current_user.display_name}/
        %li
          %label{for: "reason"} Reason for Access
          %textarea#reason{cols: "200", name: "description", value: ""} 
        %li
          %label What type of access would you require?
        - Role::ROLES.each do |role| 
          %input#roles{name: "access", type: "checkbox"}/
          %label{for: "roles"} #{role} 
    %fieldset.input-actions
      %legend Actions
      %input.primary-action{name: "invoke", type: "submit", value: "Send"}/
      %input.cancel{name: "invoke", type: "submit", value: "Cancel"}/
```

Here params[:access] only gives me if its on or not . How do i actually get the values of the selected checkbox ? .
thank you.

Comment: Is this inside of form, a rails framework form (form_for or form_tag) ??

Comment: added the entire haml just to make things easier. Yes its inside a form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the values using `value`  It'll look more like this:

```
%input#roles{name: "access", type: "checkbox", value:"#{role}"}/
```

Then for a list of `ROLES` of `Admin`, `VIP`, `user`, and a checked box of Admin, params[:access] will return:

```
Admin
```